# C# linq group by multiple times

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a an object Quiz that looks like :

```
public class Quiz
{     
    public int Id { get; set; }          
    public ICollection<MathQuiz> MathQuizzes { get; set; }     
}
```

MathQuizze object looks like :

```
public class MathQuiz
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int QuizId{ get; set; }
    public Quiz Quiz{ get; set; }

    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public Answer Answer { get; set; }

    public int TagId{ get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }

    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }

}
```

And have an object(UserQuizzes) that looks like:

```
public class UserQuizes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }


        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }


        public int QuizId { get; set; }
        public Quiz Quiz { get; set; }

}
```

UserQuizzes is just class that express many to many relationship between users and quizzes.
This is a sample data :

```
     List<Quiz> quizzes = new List<Quiz>();
        quizzes.Add(new Quiz{ Id = 1, MathQuizzes = new List<MathQuiz>{ 
                  new MathQuiz { AnswerId = 58, TagId = 1, IsCorrect = false },  
                  new MathQuiz { AnswerId = 26, TagId = 2, IsCorrect = true }, 
                  new MathQuiz { AnswerId = 57, TagId = 3, IsCorrect = true },

                  new Quiz{ Id = 2, MathQuizzes = new List<MathQuiz>{ 
                  new MathQuiz { AnswerId = 59, TagId = 1, IsCorrect = false },  
                  new MathQuiz { AnswerId = 87, TagId = 2, IsCorrect = true }, 
                  new MathQuiz { AnswerId = 25, TagId = 3, IsCorrect = true }, });

    List<UserQuizzes> userQuizzes = new List<UserQuizzes>();
        userQuizzes.Add(new Quiz{ QuizId = 1, UserId = 1},
        userQuizzes.Add(new Quiz{ QuizId = 2, UserId = 1});
```

Please don't spend too much time criticizing,  I just wanted to use something that everyone is pretty familiar with.

What i want to achieve is that  group by userquizzes by MathQuiz TagId and get data something like this:

```
TagId : 1, IsCorrect: true(0), false(2);
TagId : 2, IsCorrect: true(2), false(0);
TagId : 3, IsCorrect: true(2), false(0);
```

Comment: Type mistake, i've update the quesition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted has typos, but here is the basic idea:

```
var query =
    from q in quizzes
    from mq in q.MathQuizzes
    join uq in userQuizzes on q.Id equals uq.QuizId
    group mq by mq.TagId into g
    select new
    {
        TagId = g.Key,
        Correct = g.Sum(e => e.IsCorrect ? 1 : 0),
        Incorrect = g.Sum(e => e.IsCorrect ? 0 : 1)
    };
```

Basically you need to get the effective source set by joining the data sets, and the do the regular grouping/calculating aggregates.

Comment: It works in just a simple query, without foreach loop. Thank you nice solution !

Comment: Do you even have to join `userQuizzes`? You don't need any information of it.

Comment: Yes i dont need, i am using include eager loading which does the same thing